# Nautilus Lag on copy/cut in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, 18.04

I have a new fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

After a couple of days i noticed that whenever i try to copy or cut anything, it could be a single file or many files, as soon as i press ctrl-C there is a lag of about 2-3 seconds before i can do anything with nautilus.

During the lag, all other windows/programs function normally but nautilus is completely frozen.

After the lag nautilus works again normally and the action is carried out normally.

UPDATE:
The last few days that i am monitoring this behavior, i noticed that after some system updates, the behavior is a little different.

When my PC is booted there is no lag at all, and it starts happening after some time which i am not able to specify. And it is corrected with a reboot.

Comment: same case here under fedora 28